# Writing a variable to a txt in python throwing a few errors

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, global-variables

the code:

```
import os 
from time import *
import socket 
import time
global diskspace
#####################
#display temp
#uses shell script to find out temp then uses python to display it
#python uses os module to run line of shell script 

os.system("cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp > sysTemp")

temp = open("sysTemp") # Open a file
str = temp.read(); # read characters in sysTemp
temp.close() # close opened file
t=eval(str) # convert string into number
t2=t*2 # multiply by 2, evaluated number
t3=(t/1000.00) # convert five figure temp (milli-degrees) to degrees to two decimal places
print ("temp is:")
temperature = int(t3)
print(temperature)

def temp():
    if temperature > 60:
        print("The temp is over 60. Cool down")
    elif temperature < 40:
        print("temp is below 40")
        check()




#find name
##################
#check for internet connection
###################


#Display disk space
###################
def getDiskSpace():

    p = os.popen("df -h /")
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i = i +1
        line = p.readline()
        if i==2:
            diskspace = (line.split()[4:5])
        ds = diskspace[0]
        print("The disk space used is:")

        print(ds)
        global ds   




#Display CPU usage
###################

def getCPUuse():
    print(os.popen("top -n1 | awk '/Cpu\(s\):/ {print $2}'").readline().strip())

#Display IP
###################

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("gmail.com",80))
IP = (s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()

print("The Ip is:" + IP)

getDiskSpace()  

###################
#writing it to a .txt file

f = open("data.txt","w") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
f.write("raspberry pi data.\n")
f.write("ip:\n")
f.write(IP + "\n")
#f.write("Disk usage:" + str(ds))
f.write("temp: {0}".format(t3))
f.write("disk usage: {0}".format(ds))

f.close()


temp()

getCPUuse()

print("...")
time.sleep(10)
```

It is a program that monitors the temp, disk space, cpu usage and ip of the pi and writes it to a txt file
The main problem is with this line

```
f.write("Disk usage:" + diskspace + "\n")
```

and it says that it is not defined, I have tried many things like creating it before the def as blank but  then nothing gets written for diskspace on the text file. The other things write to the text file but not this one

the output:
temp is:
58
The Ip is:192.168.1.36
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 74, in 
    f.write("Disk usage:" + diskspace)
NameError: global name 'diskspace' is not defined

if you remove the bit about the writing bit, {'40%'] usually gets printed for diskspace.

ive added some changed code that prints the data, throws not errors but doesnt write it.

Comment: What happens if `i != 2`? when does `diskspace` get defined?

Comment: diskspace does not get printed and the usual errors get thrown. It does not get written to the text file either.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write before you actually go into your getDiskSpace() method.

Try running getDiskSpace() before you do

```
f.write("Disk usage:" + diskspace + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the global definition inside the function definition of getDiskSpace. You can't have it defined globally in the main program and have that extend inside the function.

Comment: it still doesnt write it to the text file